# How to run Django server constantly on windows

Tags: python, django

I wrote a code for a Django server, and it works perfectly inside the shell of Pycharm.
Now, I want to run this server on a local computer constantly without being inside Pycharm's shell.
Also, because it's for a client of mine I don't want any open CMD windows or any other weird GUI- I want him to just access the website like any other website.

I've seen all kinds of solutions- running runserver with &, creating a virtual machine and running the server on it and etc.

I am familiar with Vmware and all, so if the proper solution is this It's OK. But I wonder- are there any other ways to run a server on a PC without installing any additional programs?

Comment: One way or another, you will have a program (or a service) continuously running, listening on the ports - 80 and 443 like any other websites. Django recommends Apache as a tested way of building production servers on Windows

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll go with the virtual machine solution, it sounds logical and clean to do so. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Maybe I'll try using Heroku instead...